# office 365 onedrive does not support paging

Tags: onedrive

I have read the document of office 365 about onedrive. I have send two http requests:

```
1)https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$orderby=name&$top=5&$skip=0
2)https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$orderby=name&$top=5&$skip=5
```

but I have received the same result,anyone could tell me whether office 365 onedrive supports paging?

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive's paging model is a little different to skip+take. Essentially you'll make a query like:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$top=5`

and in the response you should see the usual array of values, along with a property called `@odata.nextLink`. You'll want to take that URL use it request the next page:

`"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$skiptoken=ASDGASGSD"`

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$skiptoken=ASDGASGSD`

You keep doing this until you don't get an `@odata.nextLink` returned.

Comment: Hey @Brad, there's a question here that looks like it needs your expertise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608542/client-side-paging-using-microsoft-onedrive-api-sdk/43873195?noredirect=1#comment74848227_43873195